# How to connect to EC2 instance via Jenkins pipeline?

Tags: amazon-web-services, jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-pipeline

I have configured my EC2 instance via 'adding cloud' in Jenkins and the test connection was successful. I have also added the same 'Publish over SSH key' section. But when I try to SSH to the instance via my pipeline, it's showing authentication failed.

I have also tried creating a separate folder and added the key file and created pipeline in that and tried `ssh-add -l` to check connectivity. But that is also not connecting.

Could someone tell me how to link or call the added cloud in my Jenkins pipeline? The action I want to perform is connecting to that instance and perhaps performing a touch command to check connectivity through JENKINS PIPELINE.

Comment: This functionality of Jenkins is to add build agents, which can run your build and tests. The publish over SSH is more of deploying a (successfully tested) artifact to a production server. So two different use cases. What is your goal?

Comment: @StephenKing My objective is to connect and perform some basic functionality like creating a file in EC2 instance through Jenkins pipeline.

Comment: And do you want that EC2 instance to stay for longer or is it fine, when Jenkins throws it away?

Comment: I recommend that you update your question and include your ultimate goal. I guess, it is not creating just a folder. In the current state, your question is very unclear at least to me, thus I'm voting to close.

Comment: @StephenKing I have mentioned my aim in the last line of the question,i.e. repeating the statement-to connect to EC2 instance and ensure the connection is successful by a basic action in EC2 instance like file creation.And this actions should be done through Jenkins pipeline.

Comment: Then it's probably my inability to understand the details. Hopefully somebody else knows better.

Comment: Seems not.. So I'm voting to close because it's unclear what you're asking.